# Plotting a 3D data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

This could be simple question. However, I tried/searched extensively before posting this question.

I have `struct` called `particle` and it contains a variable `particle(i).center`, which is actually a coordinate variable. I am trying to plot those coordinates using `plot3` something like,

```
hold on;
for i=1:np
  plot3(particle(i).center, 'r+')
end
```

I receive an error message saying the following:

```
Error using plot3 
Not enough input arguments.
```

I realize the error is that the variable is passed as 3x1 array instead of 3 comma separated variables. Can anyone suggest, how to plot 3D coordinates as in above case?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `plot3(particle(i).center, 'r+')` by `plot3(particle(i).center(1),particle(i).center(2),particle(i).center(3), 'r+')`?

Comment: @JensBoldsen : Thanks. It works! Maybe you could put it in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your particle structure needs to have

```
particle(i).center.x
particle(i).center.y
particle(i).center.z
```

and then `plot3(particle(i).center.x,particle(i).center.y,particle(i).center.z,...)`